# I'm trying to check if the ul html element is empty

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging, stack-overflow

Can somebody help me with this problem? I'm trying to set the `<li></li>` HTML element to `display: none;` because I want to check if than  the `<ul></ul>` will be empty.

Comment: And what's your question about this? How is it related to JS, HTML, and CSS?

Comment: Like Nico, I don't understand what your question is; where are you stuck? (As an aside, don't post pictures of code; copy the code - as text - and paste that text into the *question*; please read the "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" guidelines, then [edit] your question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply changing the `li` to "display: none" won't make the `ul` empty, as the `li` element is still inside it, even if it's not displayed. You will have to remove the `li` like so

`$('li').remove()`

In Chrome and Firefox, the `ul` still won't be recognized as empty if there is any whitespace or line breaks. If you're okay with these, add the following code

`if ($('ul').children().length == 0) {alert ('empty')}`

If you want to ensure the `ul` is *completely* empty with no whitespace or linebreaks, then add this instead

`if ($('ul').is(':empty')) {alert ('empty')}`

Comment: Yes I will done it with javascript